# move imageView from outside screen

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation

I am trying to do a move + fade in animations to an imageView.
I want it to slide from outside the screen to the middle of the screen.
here's what I have tried :

activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/city"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:id="@+id/cityImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

move.xml

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromYDelta="-70%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="1500" />
</set>
```

move function :

```
public void move(){
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cityImage);
    Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move);
    image.startAnimation(animation1);
}
```

as you can see I thought the javascript way by doing -70%p but it doesnt seem to work in android. can you please suggest me an other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your move.xml

Then add in this

```
public void move(){
    ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cityImage);

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(600.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);         
    animation.setDuration(5000);      

    img_animation.startAnimation(animation);  
}
```

Move from Right to middle

Omg 600 is too much, just use 100 in fromXdelta

Comment: how can I make it stay at the end position?